# what is that value got printed when I tried to print the string with %d?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n","Zara Ali"); // integer 
    printf("%s","Zara Ali"); // string
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code

and the output is

```
4195828
Zara Ali
```

plz somebody explain it.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, the first one is just wrong.

Comment: Why would you possibly think you can print a character string as an integer?

Comment: its not a warning.. but thanks for your answer

Comment: @KenWhite IDK i just want to now ... why such result

Comment: @Two_StiFleRS Then why does *my* compiler say `error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Werror,-Wformat]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically, the value printed is the memory location of the literal string "Zara Ali" (i.e. the memory location of the character 'Z' in your case).

As far as intent goes: it probably is not very useful to print the memory location of the string (as the comments to your post highlight).

Comment: Technically, the code has undefined behavior. The C standard says nothing about the value that will be printed.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"Technically, the value printed is the memory location"` -- I doubt this. Unless OP is using a 32-bit platform, it is likely that `sizeof(char*) > sizeof(int)`, so the `%d` format specifier is probably unable to print a whole memory address. It seems more likely to me that only a partial address is being printed. Either way, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n","Zara Ali");
```

This code has *undefined behavior* because the type of the argument (`char*`) isn't the type that's required for the `%d` format specifier (`int`).

"Undefined behavior" means that the C standard imposes no requirements on what will happen. The program could fail to compile, it could crash at run time, it could print random garbage that isn't necessarily and integer value, or literally anything else.

The most likely result is that the call will pass the address of the character string to `printf`, which will interpret that address as an `int` value. If `int` and `char*` happen to have the same size, you might get a meaningful representation of that memory address. (Use `printf("%p\n", (void*)"Zara Ali");` if you want to see a meaningful, but implementation-defined, representation of that address.)

It's also possible, but I think not typical, that integer and pointer arguments might be passed in different registers, so the garbage value printed by `printf` might be unrelated to anything.

Bottom line: The code is incorrect, and it needs to be fixed. If your goal is to create a working program, don't waste your time trying to figure out why it behaves the way it does.

If you're curious about the inner workings of the implementation you're using, exploring the behavior of code like this can be illuminating, but don't expect it to behave consistently.